# A little complex data fitting in physics which my easy code can't solve properly

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, physics

This is a data fitting in physics, however, some errors may estimate and cause failure.
First, I define:

```
E0 = 0; e = 1; k = 0.0863; T=0.4;
f[E1_] := 1/(Exp[E1/(k T)] + 1); \[Xi] = (E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma];
```

The fitting function is an integration, and the integrand is not easy:

```
(a (\[Xi] + q)^2/(1 + (\[Xi])^2) + 
   c) (-D[f[E1], E1] /. {E1 :> E1 - e V})
```

but we can firstly write it implictly, that is:

```
   (a ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma] + q)^2/(
        1 + ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma])^2) + c) (-(E^(((E1 - e V)/(
       k T)))/((1 + E^((E1 - e V)/(k T)))^2 k T)))
```

Integrate it from -infinity to infinity with respect to `E1`. But I have studied this integrand and find that we can only integrate it from `V-6 k T` to `V+ 6 k T`.
And the fitting parameter we want to get are `a,c,q and \[CapitalGamma]`.
`V` is the independent variable.

The main code I have used for fitting is:

```
sol = FindFit[data, 
   NIntegrate[(a ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma] + q)^2/(
        1 + ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma])^2) + c) (-((
       e E^((E1 - e V)/(
        k T)))/((1 + E^((E1 - e V)/(k T)))^2 k  T))), {E1, V - 6 k T, 
     V + 6 k T}], {{a, 6}, {\[CapitalGamma], 
     10}, {c, -10}, {q, -0.01}}, V];
```

As you see, I give each parameter a initial value, which I think is near the answer. But the fact is far away from ideal:

```
 FindFit::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum.
```

And the fitting outcome:

```
Show[Plot[
  NIntegrate[(a ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma] + q)^2/(
       1 + ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma])^2) + c) (-((
      e E^((E1 - e V)/(
       k T)))/((1 + E^((E1 - e V)/(k T)))^2 k  T))), {E1, V - 6 k T, 
    V + 6 k T}], {V, -100, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[data]]
Print["a=", a, Space, "\[CapitalGamma]=", \[CapitalGamma], Space, \
"c=", c, Space, "q=", q]
```

gives:
[image]

The data is:

```
 data= {{79.5, 2.82154}, {79, 2.83912}, {78.5, 2.80952}, {78, 
      2.76793}, {77.5, 2.8081}, {77, 2.83206}, {76.5, 2.83327}, {76, 
      2.8082}, {75.5, 2.80848}, {75, 2.81322}, {74.5, 2.8289}, {74, 
      2.84273}, {73.5, 2.89735}, {73, 2.92938}, {72.5, 2.95068}, {72, 
      2.94875}, {71.5, 2.94931}, {71, 2.95309}, {70.5, 2.95946}, {70, 
      3.00347}, {69.5, 3.03516}, {69, 3.07019}, {68.5, 3.06958}, {68, 
      3.09374}, {67.5, 3.11373}, {67, 3.13313}, {66.5, 3.15415}, {66, 
      3.17824}, {65.5, 3.20967}, {65, 3.20638}, {64.5, 3.22602}, {64, 
      3.21266}, {63.5, 3.2385}, {63, 3.23452}, {62.5, 3.27854}, {62, 
      3.30117}, {61.5, 3.31801}, {61, 3.31201}, {60.5, 3.30044}, {60, 
      3.31592}, {59.5, 3.32367}, {59, 3.35734}, {58.5, 3.38748}, {58, 
      3.38606}, {57.5, 3.42271}, {57, 3.43222}, {56.5, 3.4911}, {56, 
      3.46598}, {55.5, 3.4709}, {55, 3.46664}, {54.5, 3.48615}, {54, 
      3.50573}, {53.5, 3.53654}, {53, 3.56857}, {52.5, 3.54727}, {52, 
      3.53303}, {51.5, 3.5454}, {51, 3.55885}, {50.5, 3.57769}, {50, 
      3.57156}, {49.5, 3.55742}, {49, 3.49984}, {48.5, 3.47908}, {48, 
      3.48825}, {47.5, 3.50272}, {47, 3.48079}, {46.5, 3.45172}, {46, 
      3.46873}, {45.5, 3.46545}, {45, 3.47018}, {44.5, 3.48514}, {44, 
      3.53509}, {43.5, 3.58235}, {43, 3.61017}, {42.5, 3.59922}, {42, 
      3.61418}, {41.5, 3.62269}, {41, 3.65026}, {40.5, 3.67173}, {40, 
      3.67624}, {39.5, 3.70577}, {39, 3.71985}, {38.5, 3.73888}, {38, 
      3.76837}, {37.5, 3.79869}, {37, 3.84491}, {36.5, 3.84304}, {36, 
      3.84471}, {35.5, 3.84379}, {35, 3.87051}, {34.5, 3.91864}, {34, 
      3.95749}, {33.5, 3.98267}, {33, 3.98565}, {32.5, 4.00122}, {32, 
      4.03985}, {31.5, 4.09102}, {31, 4.1048}, {30.5, 4.10772}, {30, 
      4.13142}, {29.5, 4.21019}, {29, 4.25936}, {28.5, 4.28227}, {28, 
      4.27976}, {27.5, 4.31917}, {27, 4.38656}, {26.5, 4.4536}, {26, 
      4.49133}, {25.5, 4.50657}, {25, 4.49992}, {24.5, 4.56331}, {24, 
      4.60523}, {23.5, 4.67832}, {23, 4.70585}, {22.5, 4.77451}, {22, 
      4.83952}, {21.5, 4.9063}, {21, 4.96481}, {20.5, 5.00863}, {20, 
      5.06373}, {19.5, 5.15356}, {19, 5.23973}, {18.5, 5.31089}, {18, 
      5.3211}, {17.5, 5.33981}, {17, 5.39961}, {16.5, 5.46412}, {16, 
      5.56524}, {15.5, 5.63683}, {15, 5.72007}, {14.5, 5.80409}, {14, 
      5.87034}, {13.5, 5.95667}, {13, 6.04536}, {12.5, 6.17948}, {12, 
      6.30752}, {11.5, 6.40612}, {11, 6.47433}, {10.5, 6.59566}, {10, 
      6.73638}, {9.5, 6.91035}, {9, 7.05783}, {8.5, 7.16847}, {8, 
      7.30149}, {7.5, 7.46492}, {7, 7.67782}, {6.5, 7.85447}, {6, 
      8.0196}, {5.5, 8.22807}, {5, 8.44622}, {4.5, 8.67201}, {4, 
      8.8773}, {3.5, 9.17251}, {3, 9.47179}, {2.5, 9.75999}, {2, 
      10.0237}, {1.5, 10.2744}, {1, 10.5098}, {0.5, 10.6501}, {0, 
      10.6834}, {-0.5, 10.6431}, {-1, 10.5208}, {-1.5, 10.3348}, {-2, 
      10.0513}, {-2.5, 9.72523}, {-3, 9.38706}, {-3.5, 9.05965}, {-4, 
      8.73184}, {-4.5, 8.42998}, {-5, 8.13717}, {-5.5, 7.8362}, {-6, 
      7.5488}, {-6.5, 7.29268}, {-7, 7.12161}, {-7.5, 6.96772}, {-8, 
      6.82442}, {-8.5, 6.68324}, {-9, 6.55474}, {-9.5, 6.42617}, {-10, 
      6.29332}, {-10.5, 6.1594}, {-11, 6.05778}, {-11.5, 5.9511}, {-12, 
      5.83049}, {-12.5, 5.72834}, {-13, 5.62625}, {-13.5, 5.56881}, {-14, 
      5.50452}, {-14.5, 5.43584}, {-15, 5.35976}, {-15.5, 5.25725}, {-16, 
      5.20961}, {-16.5, 5.12007}, {-17, 5.04612}, {-17.5, 4.9469}, {-18, 
      4.85053}, {-18.5, 4.78029}, {-19, 4.7026}, {-19.5, 4.66133}, {-20, 
      4.62139}, {-20.5, 4.60235}, {-21, 4.58268}, {-21.5, 4.54532}, {-22, 
      4.48239}, {-22.5, 4.41735}, {-23, 4.33721}, {-23.5, 4.28537}, {-24, 
      4.22528}, {-24.5, 4.20269}, {-25, 4.19545}, {-25.5, 4.17617}, {-26, 
      4.14798}, {-26.5, 4.085}, {-27, 4.08052}, {-27.5, 4.06831}, {-28, 
      4.05404}, {-28.5, 4.00273}, {-29, 3.97587}, {-29.5, 3.95235}, {-30, 
      3.95499}, {-30.5, 3.94119}, {-31, 3.91853}, {-31.5, 3.88585}, {-32, 
      3.84712}, {-32.5, 3.80968}, {-33, 3.7666}, {-33.5, 3.73738}, {-34, 
      3.77239}, {-34.5, 3.77542}, {-35, 3.76437}, {-35.5, 3.71835}, {-36, 
      3.71675}, {-36.5, 3.70319}, {-37, 3.67479}, {-37.5, 3.62291}, {-38, 
      3.6155}, {-38.5, 3.58796}, {-39, 3.6015}, {-39.5, 3.60518}, {-40, 
      3.60824}, {-40.5, 3.59118}, {-41, 3.53468}, {-41.5, 3.49106}, {-42, 
      3.4624}, {-42.5, 3.47556}, {-43, 3.47019}, {-43.5, 3.48574}, {-44, 
      3.43451}, {-44.5, 3.43812}, {-45, 3.39936}, {-45.5, 3.40407}, {-46, 
      3.37388}, {-46.5, 3.36537}, {-47, 3.37322}, {-47.5, 3.3575}, {-48, 
      3.33553}, {-48.5, 3.3363}, {-49, 3.36193}, {-49.5, 3.37417}, {-50, 
      3.37967}, {-50.5, 3.38682}, {-51, 3.36431}, {-51.5, 3.36082}, {-52, 
      3.38405}, {-52.5, 3.41958}, {-53, 3.41028}, {-53.5, 3.38811}, {-54, 
      3.37696}, {-54.5, 3.38285}, {-55, 3.35724}, {-55.5, 3.3389}, {-56, 
      3.33704}, {-56.5, 3.33506}, {-57, 3.35542}, {-57.5, 3.33274}, {-58, 
      3.33308}, {-58.5, 3.33823}, {-59, 3.34999}, {-59.5, 3.39393}, {-60, 
      3.38592}, {-60.5, 3.37492}, {-61, 3.35596}, {-61.5, 3.37239}, {-62, 
      3.41898}, {-62.5, 3.42631}, {-63, 3.40993}, {-63.5, 3.39746}, {-64, 
      3.37633}, {-64.5, 3.3749}, {-65, 3.33873}, {-65.5, 3.3423}, {-66, 
      3.34293}, {-66.5, 3.36338}, {-67, 3.34868}, {-67.5, 3.34209}, {-68, 
      3.33832}, {-68.5, 3.34795}, {-69, 3.31658}, {-69.5, 3.30106}, {-70, 
      3.28018}, {-70.5, 3.32798}, {-71, 3.32498}, {-71.5, 3.3319}, {-72, 
      3.2746}, {-72.5, 3.2815}, {-73, 3.25723}, {-73.5, 3.28271}, {-74, 
      3.28464}, {-74.5, 3.30894}, {-75, 3.29525}, {-75.5, 3.28636}, {-76, 
      3.28622}, {-76.5, 3.27369}, {-77, 3.28231}, {-77.5, 3.28308}, {-78, 
      3.30555}, {-78.5, 3.28956}, {-79, 3.26094}, {-79.5, 3.24725}, {-80, 
      3.2256}}
```

I have cost nearly a week in this data fitting with no result, I wish you could rescue me if you read this, I express my heartfelt gratitude.

Comment: I have used stack Exchange not long, if there is something unclear, please say to me.

Comment: Parameter `V` isn't defined.

Comment: V is the variable of fitting function. For y=a x, it's the x, and the parameter I want get is a.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to separate the `NIntgerate` from `FindFit`:

```
model[V_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, \[CapitalGamma]_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(a ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma] +q)^2/(1 + ((E1 - E0)/\[CapitalGamma])^2) + c) (-((e E^((E1 - e V)/(k T)))/((1 + E^((E1 - e V)/(k T)))^2 k T)))
, {E1, V - 6 k T,V + 6 k T}]

sol = FindFit[data, model[V, a, \[CapitalGamma], c,q], {{a, 6}, {\[CapitalGamma], 10}, {c, -10}, {q,-0.01}}, V]
(*{a -> 6.86561, \[CapitalGamma] -> 10.3985, c ->-10.0443, q -> -0.0240009}*)

Show[{ListPlot[data], 
Plot[model[V , a /. sol, \[CapitalGamma]/. sol, c /. sol,q /. sol], {V,-100, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange ->All]}]
```

[image]